# Django admin panel doesn't let me to edit CharField

Tags: python, django-models

I am having this code on my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here. 
class Feature(models.Model):  
    name: models.CharField(max_length=100)   
    details: models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I have added the app name on the installed apps section, and run the migrations properly.
I can see the Feature table on my admin panel, but it won't let me to add name or details field, and when I hit add it is showing me this field with no textfield to add:

[image: Admin Panel]

Comment: Use `=` instead of `:` when defining model fields - `name = models.CharField(max_length=100)`. You are creating annotations on your model class

Comment: You are right Selcuk, that was the issue.
Thanks a lot